# Java POI Issues with setting the border lines

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

RegionUtil function is properly working for POI 3.17 library. But it is not a static one. I cant use it for the lower versions of POI. Could please someone help me for a static function which is working perfectly fine for all POI releases?

Comment: So you found a function in RegionUtil that was added in version 3.17, but you are looking for a similar function that works in all versions of POI? I'm guessing it doesn't exist or it wouldn't have been added in 3.17. POI is a currently active project. New things are being added regularly. If you need the most recent additions, you need to use the most recent version of the library.

Comment: okay..Thanks for the reply...my doubt is that the Regionutil is specific for 3.17..we cant deliver such things to production level now..so im thinking about the alternate solution which probably works like the same

Comment: Let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: The beauty of an open source project is.... it's open source! If you're constrained to using an older version of Apache POI, you can check out the code, merge the RegionUtil changes, and create your own jar. You could also copy-paste the code into a static utility class in your project (so long as you abide by POI's ASL 2.0 license terms) and call there. It's possible RegionUtil isn't fully self-contained, so you may need to merge in a few other changes to get this working, but that's the disadvantage of running an old version of software and needing new features.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now im having some other major problems..RegionUtil is not at all a big issue for the time being. Im using NetBeans IDE1.7 and ApachePOI 3.17..when im generating an Excel sheet, some fields are hidden..I need to drag it for the view..pls respond for this problem??